# Webscraping on Netflix Top 10 not working correctly, my code is not able to scrape the second page

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape top10.netflix.com for the values of the last 2 years.

Here is my code:

```
n_weeks= 104
types=['films','films-non-english','tv','tv-non-english']


for type in types:
    #First page
    url_base= 'https://top10.netflix.com/'
    week=datetime.date(2023,4,2)
    url= url_base + type + "?week=" + week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    page= requests.get(url, headers=get_user_agent(), proxies=get_free_proxy())
    soup= BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    table= soup.find('table', class_='w-full text-sm table-fixed md:text-base')
    Top10 = pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0]
    Top10['Date']=week
    Top10 = Top10.rename(columns={Top10.columns[1]: 'Title'})

    print(f"Completata la settimana {week} di {type}")

    #Other pages
    for i in range(n_weeks):
        week= week - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        url= url_base + type + "?week=" + week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        page= requests.get(url, headers=get_user_agent(), proxies=get_free_proxy())
        soup= BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
        table= soup.find('table', class_='w-full text-sm table-fixed md:text-base')

        if table:
            df = pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0]
            df['Date']=week
        else:
            print(f'Errore riscontrato alla settimana {week} di {type}')
            break
        df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]: 'Title'})

        Top10= pd.concat([Top10,df])
        print(f"Completata la settimana {week} di {type}")

    Top10.to_csv(f"C:/Users/User_/OneDrive/Desktop/Netflix Green/{type}.csv", index=False)
    print(f"Completato il caricamento di {type}")


print("Caricamento completato")
```

My problem is that the temporary dataFrame "df", that I use to collect data on page 2+ and add to the main one, have the same values of the first dataFrame "Top10"( except for the "Date" column that get changed manually every for loop)

I already checked if the urls were wrong, but they should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The data is dynamically loaded with JS from a JSON.

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.34",
}
netflix_top_ten = "https://top10.netflix.com/_next/data/JuqbTeJvFiWDor4mQvG4s/index.json"
data = requests.get(netflix_top_ten, headers=headers).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["pageProps"]["data"]["weeklyTopTen"])
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="github"))
```

To get this:

```
|    |   showId |       id |     week |   rank |   weeksInTopTen |    hours | category   | name                     | showName                 | seasonName               |
|----|----------|----------|----------|--------|-----------------|----------|------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|  0 | 81212842 | 81212842 | 20230402 |      1 |               1 | 64420000 | films      | Murder Mystery 2         | Murder Mystery 2         | Murder Mystery 2         |
|  1 | 80242619 | 80242619 | 20230402 |      2 |               2 | 24690000 | films      | Murder Mystery           | Murder Mystery           | Murder Mystery           |
|  2 | 81280035 | 81280035 | 20230402 |      3 |               4 | 12700000 | films      | Luther: The Fallen Sun   | Luther: The Fallen Sun   | Luther: The Fallen Sun   |
|  3 | 80209222 | 80209222 | 20230402 |      4 |               2 |  8280000 | films      | I See You                | I See You                | I See You                |
|  4 | 80234520 | 80234520 | 20230402 |      5 |               3 |  6330000 | films      | The Magician's Elephant  | The Magician's Elephant  | The Magician's Elephant  |
|  5 | 81198916 | 81198916 | 20230402 |      6 |               6 |  3540000 | films      | Minions: The Rise of Gru | Minions: The Rise of Gru | Minions: The Rise of Gru |
|  6 | 80048061 | 80048061 | 20230402 |      7 |               3 |  3260000 | films      | Hotel Transylvania 2     | Hotel Transylvania 2     | Hotel Transylvania 2     |
|  7 | 81020485 | 81020485 | 20230402 |      8 |               3 |  3240000 | films      | Dragged Across Concrete  | Dragged Across Concrete  | Dragged Across Concrete  |
|  8 | 80108182 | 80108182 | 20230402 |      9 |               6 |  3210000 | films      | Trolls                   | Trolls                   | Trolls                   |
|  9 | 70230638 | 70230638 | 20230402 |     10 |               1 |  3200000 | films      | The Bourne Legacy        | The Bourne Legacy        | The Bourne Legacy        |
```

Comment: Your code only get the "Top 10 most popular english films based on hours viewed in the first 28 days" which is a table at the bottom of the page that is "static" and that I'm not interested to. What I was trying to get is the first table [weeklyTopTen] in the Json for every week in the past 2 years. How did you get that url? I'm still a new to programing

Comment: It was supposed to push you in the right direction. Learn about [Dev Tools](https://firefox-dev.tools/); all modern browsers have them.